# How to handle non unique item GUIDs/IDs in an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feedparser, atom-feed

What is the correct response an RSS client should have when it encounters a feed that has multiple items with the same guid/identifier?

Currently in my application, any items that use an existing guid won't be cached or displayed because it believes it already has that item.

In this [example feed](http://us.blizzard.com/diablo3/feed/en-US/atom.xml) a lot of items share this id:

```
tag:blizzard.com,2010-10-22:diablo3:feed:en-us:1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [w3 when there are duplicate entries in an RSS feed](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/DuplicateEntries.html):

> Atom Processors MAY choose to display all of them or some subset of them. One typical behavior would be to display only the entry with the latest atom: updated timestamp.

I would go with the spec and display only the entry with the latest updated timestamp.  Don't forget to send an email to Blizzard support and have them get [their RSS validated](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fus.blizzard.com%2Fdiablo3%2Ffeed%2Fen-US%2Fatom.xml) - just don't threaten to keep them out of the next raid.

Take care.

Answer (score 5):

I think your app is doing it right. Don't get fancy. If you've already seen an item with that guid you don't present it a second time. You should contact whe webmaster for the feed if possible and alert them to the problem.

Comment: I agree.  In my experience, the more you try to correct for mistakes in specific feeds, the more you find yourself causing problems dealing with other ones.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried some fancy things and just ended up with bugs in valid feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Does each item have a unique URL? If so, fall back to using the URL.